# Android theme Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog equivalent in Froyo GingerBread?

Tags: android

I have the following code in my style.xml in values folder

```
 <style name="LightDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

and the below code in my style.xml in values-v11 folder

```
<style name="LightDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

The problem is when the android version is less than 3.0(honeycomb) the dialog does not go white but goes white above 3.0 as it takes it from the values-v11 folder. What is the equivalent of `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog` prior honeycomb and does Google provide a place where we can compare this? Can somebody help me out on this?Thanks in advance.